# how to keep the choosed data in the <select> element? HTML

Tags: php, html

here I have stupid question, hope you can help me.

I create a menu using Select element and option like this:

```
<option selected="selected">Select type...</option>
<option value="1">Doctor</option>
<option value="2">Patient</option>
```

and every time I need to pick one value from this menu and use the submit button next to it to transfer data.
But every time the page refreshed, this menu will reveal: Select type...
I want it to reveal the value I chose last time, but don't know how.

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: +1 For 'choosed'. That's my new favourite word :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to move that selected="selected" onto the selected option.

Doing so in PHP isn't too rough. Just check the $_POST or $_GET (however you sent the form) value for your select box, such as $_POST["selectBox"] for each value down the list. When you find a match, echo out the selected="selected" string there. If the value was empty, output it on your default value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to populate the `<select>` options in an array, then loop through it to display the `<option>` list and mark them as selected is the $_POST variable matches the correct value:

```
<?php $myselect = array(1=>'Doctor', 2=>'Patient'); ?>
<select name="myselect">
   <option>Select type...</option>
   <?php foreach ($myselect as $value => $label): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php if (isset($_POST['myselect']) && $_POST['myselect'] == $value) echo ' selected'; ?>>
      <?php echo $label; ?>
   </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="myselect">
    <?php
        $myselect = array('Select type...','Doctor','Patient');             
        for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++){
            echo "<option value=\"{myselect[$i]}\"";
            if (isset($_POST['myselect']) && $_POST['myselect'] == $myselect[$i]){ 
            echo 'selected=\"selected\"';
            }
            echo ">{$myselect[$i]}</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the server-side language of you choice to store the selected value in a database, xml or text file.
Edit : I think I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

On submit you can save that value as a $_SESSION value and use that to set the select on page load.

Using Javascript you can either set a cookie on change or alter the url to add a parameter (url?selecttype=1) and set that on page load using PHP.

There's a good use of cookies in JS on quirksmode: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change which one is selected to match the request....

```
 function create_select($properties, $opts)
 {
    $out="<select ";
    foreach ($properties as $propname=>$propval) {
       $out.=" $propname='$propval'";
    }
    $out.=">\n";
    foreach ($opts as $val=>$caption) {
        $out.="<option value='$value'";
        if ($_REQUEST[$properties['name']]==$val) $out.=" SELECTED";
        $out.=">$caption</option>\n";
    }
    $out.="</select>";
    return $out;
 }
 print create_select(array('name'=>'direction',
                    'id'=>'direction',
                    'class'=>'colourful',
                    'onChange'=>''),
              array('N'=>'North',
                    'S'=>'South',
                    'E'=>'East',
                    'W'=>'West'));
```